# SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock issue caused by INSERT trigger on concurrent access

Tags: mysql, concurrency, triggers, transactions, innodb

I found a SQL deadlock issue which occurs when the function is executed concurrently by two users. I have a PHP function which executes several database insert queries which enclose in a transaction. And one of the inserts fires a trigger as well. See my table schema and code sample below.

**main_table**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `main_table` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `action_time` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**history_table**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `history_table` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `action_time` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `audit_id` INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**audit_table**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `audit_table` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `action_time` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have a trigger on *main_table*, defined as follows. What it does is that selecting the max id from *audit_table* and insert a record to the *history_table*.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER watch_insert_main_table
AFTER INSERT ON main_table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE max_id INT;
    SET max_id = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `audit_table`) + 1;
    INSERT INTO `history_table` SET audit_id=max_id;
END;
```

Following is the function which is executed by two users concurrently. *insertRecord* funtion simply inserts a record to the given table.

```php
try {
    $dbConnection->beginTransaction();
    $this->insertRecord('main_table');    
    $this->insertRecord('audit_table');
    $dbConnection->commit();    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $dbConnection->rollback();    
}
```

I get the following dead lock error when the function is called for the second time (concurrently).

```
40001 - SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

If I do either of the following changes, this issue won't occur.

- Remove the enclosed transaction in the PHP code
- Remove *$this->insertRecord('audit_table');* line from the PHP code
- Modify the trigger so that it doesn't have a select statement from the audit_table

I want to know the **root cause of this issue**. Is another transaction being starting from the MySQL trigger when it is fired? How are the transactions and locks working inside a trigger?

I found that the following two questions are also related to a similar issue.

- [MySQL Deadlock with an an insert that raises a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618799/mysql-deadlock-with-an-an-insert-that-raises-a-trigger)
- [Deadlock caused by INSERT trigger - thread looking for lock it already has?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90233/deadlock-caused-by-insert-trigger-thread-looking-for-lock-it-already-has)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this simplification helps:

```
CREATE TRIGGER watch_insert_main_table
AFTER INSERT ON main_table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `history_table` (audit_id)
        SELECT MAX(`id`)+1 FROM `audit_table`;
END;
```

Notice how it combines your two statements into a single statement.  This *may* avoid letting another connection get in there and grab the same `id` (or something to that effect).

The following *may* be related (provided by OP):  This happens due to a [known issue](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67452) in MySQL. Setting a variable from a select acquires a lock when using read uncommitted isolation level. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151837/in-mysql-why-does-setting-a-variable-from-a-select-acquire-a-lock-when-using-rea) has more information.

Are you using isolation mode Read Uncommitted?  If so, why?

Comment: Yes! This solves the problem. What I wanted to know is that the root cause for this issue. I found that the issue happens due to a known issue in mysql. I will edit your answer and add more information.

Comment: @PathumHarshana - I provided my rationale for suggesting the code and I rescued your comment, but... Are you using isolation mode Read Uncommitted? If so, why?